# Real analytic recursion

Tags: real-analysis, ds.dynamical-systems

Fix an analytic function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$. Assume $f(x)>x$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$.

Is there an analytic function $g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $g(x+1)=f(g(x))$?

Comment: If $f$ has a fixed point $c$, the constant $g(x)=c$ works. Is this fine (which means that the interesting case is when $f(x)>x$ for all $x$ or $f(x)<x$ for all $x$, or do you want to require $g$ to be non-constant?

Comment: @YCor I added a hypothesis.

Comment: Apparently there is an analytic solution for $f(x)=e^x$: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration#Complex_heights

Comment: Note: if one requires $g$ to be an analytic self-diffeomorphism and writes $T(x)=x+1$, this rewrites $T=g^{-1}\circ f\circ g$, that is, this means that $g$ conjugates $T$ to the translation $T$.